# Removing invisible question mark from text - #​E using vba

Tags: vba

I have to read the text from the cells of a column in excel and search for it in another sheet.

say for example, the text in sheet1 column A is "Evoked Potential Amplitude N2 - P2." This has to be searched in sheet2 column C. This fails because a question mark appears before the "E" which is not present in the value in the sheet2.

[image: the character looks like this] Both are representation of same character in different application. Maybe someone might recognize it.

In the excel sheet I don't see any junk characters, but while handling it in the vb code I see a question mark before the word - Evoke.

This data was extracted from a share point application and this character (?) is not visible to the plain eye. Search and replace functions are not working in this case.

Comment: What the chapter code for the "junk" character?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by chapter code and how to get it?

Comment: @Tim Williams, do you mean Character code?

Comment: @TimWilliams i don't know the character. But have put a screen shot of it. here is a sample of the character "​E". may be you can try to view in your editor

Comment: I don't think that's a question mark. It appears to be a placeholder for a Unicode (multi-byte) character that isn't present in the current font. Check the two sheets to see what the font is for the cells you're trying to match; if they're not, and one is Unicode and the other not, they won't match.

Comment: Yes, I meant **character** code. Stupid auto-correction...

Comment: @TimWilliams I copied the character "​E" to [site](http://slayeroffice.com/tools/ascii/) and it shows character code as 8203. not sure how to test if it is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode 8203 is a zero-width space. I'm not sure where it's coming from. It is probably a flaw in the way the data is imported into Excel which you haven't noticed before, but it might be worth fixing.

In the meantime, you can simply use the Mid() function in Excel VBA to remove the unwanted character. For example instead of

```
x = cells(1,1).value
```

use

```
x = Mid(cells(1,1).value,2)
```

which deletes the first character.